# Querying MySQL via ActiveRecord error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR.  I am trying to see if my MySQL connection got set up correctly.
I have this code in my controller:

```
require 'rubygems' # Only if installed via RubyGems

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  User.find(1)

  def index
  end
end
```

and this in my user.rb class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And obviously I have a user table in MySQL.

I get an error like this:

```
undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea why?  And also, how can I take the query code out of the Controller and into a Model type of file?

Comment: Why do you want to move the `find` call into the model?  `find` already is a method defined on the model.

Comment: Could you include the first few lines of the backtrace that caused this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code should look more like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(1)
  end
end
```

And you should query your model in controller - ofc when using basic finds etc.

In more complicated cases, you should use scopes:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: are you sure that you're table exists, and you have there record with id=1?

Comment: plus, if the record was not there with that id, it would return a different error probably, right?

Comment: Actually, when I restarted the server, I got this error: !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'  -- what is the diff with mysql and mysql2 gems?  Should I really add the mysql2 gem? Or is the error a strange one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `User.find(1)` into the `index` action.

Comment: did that, but still have the undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass error

Comment: @@thefugal no luck with either solution